# How to hide some contents from the PowerPoint slides, also which needs hidden from the selection pane?

Tags: openxml, presentationml

I am working on PowerPoint slides, I am looking for hiding some of the contents from slides. The files I am going to make hidden should not be displayed or should not able to modify from the selection pane. Is there any solution for this guys ? I have tried some techniques there,

1.changed the text colour to the background colour.
2.edited the visible attribute value to false.
3.modified the tags noEdit , noSelection , noSearch etc for hiding contents from the slide.

The contents were then disappeared from the slides but it was displayed on the selection pane.

I just wanted to hide the contents from the slides and which cannot be accessed from the selection pane windows also.

Please help guys. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you want to hide some info from the slide, what is the purpose of having it from the first place? you can simply remove it if you don't want it. Otherwise, you can hide the slide from the slide show or split the initial slide in more and hide those you don't want or use hyperlinks from slideHidden to slideShow?1

Comment: Thanks for your reply TassosK , actually I just want to represent each slide in the presentation uniquely. The purpose is to search with the content search option in OneDrive.  If I search with the value added in the slide, the content search should show the presentation containing the slide.